# Plotting complex functions using the Symbolic Math Toolbox?

Tags: math, plot, matlab, complex-numbers

How should I plot this function:

`z^(1/n)` [complex roots of z]

with `ezsurf()`, `ezmesh()`, ...? In the official documentation is clearly stated that `ezsurf()` and `ezsurfc()` for example, do not accept complex inputs.

I understand the trick is probably in using both `real()` and `imag()` functions, but even so, I can't get rid of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic idea seems to work for me alright. Of course you can go on to tweak the axis limits, grid spacing, color look-up table, etc.. The online documentation at http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/ezsurf.html has some nice examples that aren't found in the built-in help system. Good luck!

```
syms z n
subplot(2,1,1)
ezsurf(real(z^(1/n)))
subplot(2,1,2)
ezsurf(imag(z^(1/n)))
```

[image]

Comment: That was really simpler than i thought. Thank you very much!